# C# MemoryStream.Read() always reads same part

Tags: c#, buffer, arrays, memorystream

Edit: Solution is at bottom of post

I am trying my luck with reading binary files. Since I don't want to rely on `byte[] AllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(myPath)`, because the binary file might be rather big, I want to read small portions of the same size (which fits nicely with the file format to read) in a loop, using what I would call a "buffer".

```
    public void ReadStream(MemoryStream ContentStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[sizePerHour];
        for (int hours = 0; hours < NumberHours; hours++)
        {                
            int t = ContentStream.Read(buffer, 0, sizePerHour);
            SecondsToAdd = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);

           // further processing of my byte[] buffer
        }
    }
```

My stream contains all the bytes I want, which is a good thing. When I enter the loop several things cease to work.
My `int t` is `0`although I would presume that `ContentStream.Read()` would process information from within the stream to my bytearray, but that isn't the case.

I tried `buffer = ContentStream.GetBuffer()`, but that results in my buffer containing all of my stream, a behaviour I wanted to avoid by using reading to a buffer.

Also resetting the stream to position 0 before reading did not help, as did specifying an offset for my `Stream.Read()`, which means I am lost.

Can anyone point me to reading small portions of a stream to a byte[]? Maybe with some code?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Pointing me to the right direction was the answer, that `.Read()` returns `0` if the end of stream is reached. I modified my code to the following:

```
    public void ReadStream(MemoryStream ContentStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[sizePerHour];

        ContentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //Added this line
        for (int hours = 0; hours < NumberHours; hours++)
        {                
            int t = ContentStream.Read(buffer, 0, sizePerHour);
            SecondsToAdd = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);

           // further processing of my byte[] buffer
        }
    }
```

And everything works like a charm. I initially reset the stream to its origin every time I iterated over `hour` and giving an offset. Moving the "set to beginning-Part" outside my look and leaving the offset at 0 did the trick.

Comment: What is the value  of `sizePerHour` (in the debugger) ?

Comment: In the first iteration, my buffer[] is still filled with `0`s, in the second iteration I get an `ArgumentException` saying, offset and/or length of array are outside the valid bounds. Why is my buffer[] filled with `0` after the first iteration? The value of sizePerHour is 446404, the size of my stream is 74995872.

Answer (score 2):

Read returns zero if the end of the stream is reached. Are you sure, that your memory stream has the content you expect? I´ve tried the following and it works as expected:

```
// Create the source of the memory stream.
UInt32[] source = {42, 4711};
List<byte> sourceBuffer = new List<byte>();
Array.ForEach(source, v => sourceBuffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(v)));

// Read the stream.
using (MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream(sourceBuffer.ToArray()))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof (UInt32)];
    int t;
    do
    {
        t = contentStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (t > 0)
        {
           UInt32 value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
        }
    } while (t > 0);
}
```